# Is there a way to pause a loop and continue it weekly?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I am trying to copy row 6 in my google sheets to the next row (row 7) in formula only and then copy in value to the same row (row 6) so that there is no longer a formula there. I want this to happen every week for 13 weeks,as this is a historisation process that we are trying to implement. I was able to do everything with Apps Script except for the fact that the code that I have makes it all the at same time which means right after I run the code, I get 12 rows of the same value and then the last row with the formula which I do not want. I searched online and someone said to build in a settimout function which does not seem to work.

This is the code that I am trying right now and which does not seem to work:

```
function waitforme(everyMinutes){
return new Promise(resolve =>{
setTimeout(()=>{resolve('')},everyMinutes(60*24*7));
})
s = 6;
s=s++;
console.log(s)
async function myFunction() {
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
await waitforme ();
for(i=s;i<s+11;i++){
var targetrow = activeSheet.getRange(i,2,1,3).getFormulaR1C1();
activeSheet.getRange(i+1,2,1,3).setFormulaR1C1(targetrow);
var targetrow = activeSheet.getRange(i,2,1,3).getValue();
activeSheet.getRange(i,2,1,3).setValue(targetrow);
}
}}
```

Here is the link for the google sheets as well: I simplified everything that I want to easy numbers so that it is easy to deal with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KfrysAwFC5SrHFr9lbOFu2Gp4QPzg_oVG-auEkWOGIY/edit#gid=0

Comment: Try a timebased trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order tot execute some logic once a week you should set an interval for that, like in this example (is not the right answer, but is the simplest one):

```js
// MILISECONDS_IN_A_SECOND = 1000;
function main() {
  setInterval(() => {
    // exec code
  }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
}
```

Comment: When I add this instead of the settimeout function it just gives me a bunch of errors

Comment: That's for clientside javascript not Google Server Code. Try timebased trigger instead.

Comment: @Cooper but how can the timebased trigger influence the loop. This is what I do not get. The timebased trigger would just influence when the loop is run but not the intervals within the loop

Comment: You can't run a loop for a week.   Most scripts have to finish within 6 minutes depending upon your account type they can last as long as 30 minutes and perhaps more but it will be something measured in minutes not days.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Scripts, they actually have their own way of scheduling script execution.

If you have the script open, hover over to the sidebar on the left, and click "Triggers". Then click "Add Trigger", and you will be given a menu that should allow you to set a function to be executed every week.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But a trigger would only influence when the loop is run. My problem is that I want the elements in the leep to have weekly intervals. Meaning that in my case I want i=s for the first week but then i=s+1 for the second week and i=s+2 for the third and so on. What happens now is that everything runs the second the script is executed. Rights now the rows of the whole quarter get filled in even though I want it weekly.